# Chart.js library V.2 change Cursor to not allowed

Tags: javascript, chart.js

When using the Chart.js library V.2, I want to change cursor to 'not-allowed 'when hovering the mouse over the barchart.

Here is my code

```
            // Draw Chart
        var ctx = document.getElementById("main").getContext("2d");

        ctx.canvas.width = calculatedWidth;
        ctx.canvas.height = calculatedHeight || 400;
        mainDashboardChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: dashboardDatas,
            yLabels: 0,
            options: dashboardOptions('noSubChart', suggestedMaxVal, subChartDataLength)
        });
```

I cannot find a way to do this. Does anybody know if this is possible?

Comment: Have you tried using CSS for this? Like #main{cursor:not-allowed;}

Comment: Then the entire canvas will get that property, not only the active chart regions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be able to get the active point with `getElementAtEvent` method.

So the code will be

```
var helpers = Chart.helpers;
helpers.bindEvents(mainDashboardChart, ["mousemove", "touchstart", "touchmove", "mouseout"], function(evt){
var activeElement = mainDashboardChart.getElementAtEvent(evt);
$('#main').css('cursor',activeElement.length ? 'not-allowed' : 'default'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can play with the `hover` option like this :

```
hover: {
    onHover: function(e) {
        $("#myChart").css("cursor", e[0] ? "pointer" : "default");
    }
}
```

Working example on a doughnut chart: https://jsfiddle.net/Tintin37/s9m6mggL/1/